# How do I stop Alexa app from crashing on open

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Alexa app keeps crashing and giving this summary

```
`
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot make a new request because the previous respons[text](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)e is still open: please call response.close()

```
at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange$okhttp(Transmitter.kt:14)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:5)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:10)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:1)

at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:20)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:10)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:1)

at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:22)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:10)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:6)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:10)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:1)

at com.amazon.clouddrive.cdasdk.RequestLoggingInterceptor.intercept(RequestLoggingInterceptor.java:3)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:10)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:1)

at com.amazon.clouddrive.cdasdk.RetryInterceptor.intercept(RetryInterceptor.java:3)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:10)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:1)

at com.amazon.clouddrive.cdasdk.StandardHeaderInterceptor.intercept(StandardHeaderInterceptor.java:6)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:10)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:1)

at com.amazon.clouddrive.cdasdk.TokenAuthenticator.intercept(TokenAuthenticator.java:4)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:10)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:1)

at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:13)

at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:6)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

```
`
```

Happens everytime I open Alexa app. Cleared cache, cleared data, reinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the Alexa app on your android phone right?
As this app isn't open source you can't do anything to fix it or look into it further.

- You could try to get in customer contact with Amazon / app creator.
- try to update the app via playstore (I have version 2.2487227.0)